Aggregation: Category missing in SQL subquery
my base data:



Process ID
Location
Date
Timeliness




2030608
New York
May 24
in time


2067393
Ohio
May 24
overdue


1329306
Ohio
May 24
in time


1740814
Ohio
June 24
overdue


1924676
Chicago
May 24
overdue


1985313
Chicago
May 24
overdue


1715694
San Fransisco
June 24
in time


1981887
San Fransisco
June 24
overdue


1752416
San Fransisco
July 24
overdue


1671006
New York
May 24
in time


2030607
New York
June 24
in time



and I want to aggregate it to use it in a visualisation tool.
Current output of my aggregation query:



Location
Date
intime
total
percentage




New York
May 24
3
3
100


Ohio
May 24
1
2
50


San Fransisco
June 24
1
2
50



My problem: certain data drops out of the aggregation because there are no intime processes at that location and month.
The output that I need: (follows directly from the base data above)



Location
Date
intime
total
percentage




New York
May 24
3
3
100


Ohio
May 24
1
2
50


Ohio
June 24
0
1
0


San Fransisco
June 24
1
2
50


San Fransisco
July 24
0
1
0


Chicago
May 24
0
2
0



The query that I am currently using for aggregation is:
SELECT
    gesamt2.Location,
    gesamt2.date,
    intime2.anzahl AS intime,
    gesamt2.anzahl AS total,

    CAST(intime2.anzahl AS float) / CAST(gesamt2.anzahl AS float) * 100 AS percentage

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            location,
            anzahl,
            date
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    Location,
                    Date,
                    timeliness,
                    COUNT(1) AS anzahl
                FROM
                    basedata
                GROUP BY ROLLUP (Location, Date, Timeliness)
            ) AS gesamt
        WHERE
            (timeliness IS NULL)
    ) AS gesamt2
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            mapping, anzahl, date
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    Location,
                    Date,
                    timeliness,
                    COUNT(1) AS anzahl
                FROM
                    basedata
                WHERE
                    (BASE_FINAL_APPROVAL > GETDATE() - 366)
                GROUP BY ROLLUP (Location, Date, timeliness)
            ) AS intime
        WHERE
            (timeliness = 'in time')
    ) AS intime2 ON
        gesamt2.Location = intime2.Location
        AND
        gesamt2.date = intime2.date


I think your SQL query can be made significantly more readable and maintainable if you replace the inner-queries with named CTEs; it will also eliminate the duplication of the two basedata queries.

There's a major problem with your query: you're using GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP in your inner-queries, which means the additional aggregate rows will have NULL in the named columns like Location, which means your INNER JOIN ... .Location = .Location will fail.

The query is much simpler if you use conditional aggregation.
SELECT *, ROUND(intime/total*100, 0) as percentage
FROM
    (SELECT Location, 
           [Date], 
           SUM(CASE WHEN Timeliness='in time' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as intime,
           COUNT(*) as total
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Location, [Date]) agg 
;      


or with CTE
WITH agg AS 
(SELECT Location, 
       [Date], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Timeliness='in time' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as intime,
       COUNT(*) as total
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Location, [Date])  

SELECT *, ROUND(intime/total*100, 0) percentage
FROM agg

The above was not tested in SQL Server.
MySQL Demo

Thank you very much. The conditional aggregation is working and solved the problem!
